# Getting a comment from my stream

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

How can i get a full length posting/comment? 
With

```
SELECT post_id,  message, message_tags, description, description_tags FROM stream WHERE source_id = me()
```

i m getting a "cut" version of my posted comments (in the message field).

Using graph with the post_id brings me still the same trimmed message as result.
Is there a other "table" to query comments by post_id?

An example can be found below.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `comments` field

`SELECT post_id,  comments FROM stream WHERE source_id = me()`

You should read [FQL - Stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) documentation page

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enough. Here an example: i leave a comment "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla this is the long comment which i want to fetch later" on a fanpage. The description field in my query gives me a result like 'bla bla...' on fanpage". Your query results are only comments to my postings - so comments to the blabla-post, a level to deep ;)

Comment: @inselberg Well your original question was "How can i get a full length comment?"
can you give a post ID to investigate ? you wrote "An example can be found below." with no example

Comment: Below in the comments. Maybe it was a confusing choice to name that what i m looking for a "comment". As you can see in post_id 1251817337_10200582728151293, the story field contains not everything that i wrote and "this" is what i need to query. (btw i know why a reduced text is stored in the "story" or/and "description" fields.)